# XSD Schema Validation Error: DOMDocument schemaValidate(): Element 'Body': No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: php, xml, dom, xsd

XML Gurus,

I'm having trouble validating a DOM document in PHP using an XSD file. Any ideas?

- Verified document is valid (tested with other tools)
- Verified XSD file is being accessed by PHP (by removing it and seeing the error)
- Verified DOMdocument is correct prior to calling validation

Sample XML

```
<Message xmlns="http://www.org.org/schema/DOCUMENT" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="010" release="006" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.org.org/schema/DOCUMENT SS_DOCUMENT_XML_10_6MU.xsd">
   <Header>
      <To Qualifier="P">3365310</To>
      <From Qualifier="D">6438058169001</From>
      <MessageID>52e2a28345cf152e2a2836e3c1</MessageID>
      <SentTime>2014-01-24T09:27:31.5Z</SentTime>
      <PrescriberOrderNumber>PON12341</PrescriberOrderNumber>
   </Header>
   <Body>
   <!-- more content here, removed for sample -->
   </Body>
</Message>
```

Sample XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.org.org/schema/DOCUMENT" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.org.org/schema/DOCUMENT" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <!-- Message -->
    <xs:element name="Message" type="MessageType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="MessageType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Header" type="HeaderType"/>
            <xs:element name="Body" type="BodyType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <!-- More complex types are here, removed for sample -->
</xs:schema>
```

Sample PHP

```
$doc->schemaValidate('SS_DOCUMENT_XML_10_6MU.xsd')
```

Error Message

```
Message:  DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Element 'Body': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
```

Comment: Sanity check: Try dumping your $doc right before validating.

Comment: Yes, it is the same document.

Comment: Well, [brought back to its essentials this works](http://codepad.org/I6076UwO)... How did you define `BodyType`?

Comment: I'm sensing that the issue got pruned away in the pursuit of brevity.  For example, people have [gotten tripped up on properly constructing a document using namespaced elements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10032101/290085).  We may miss such issues if we're assuming that you're reading in the document from a file or pulling it off the wire.  Countless other unanticipated sources of problems could exist in unposted code.  @JK, can you post the smallest *complete* example that still exhibits the problem?  Thanks.